# Are cabin air car filters a standard size?

Tags: cabin-filter

I'm aiming to replace my 2010 Civic's air filter. While looking online to see what stores have it, I noticed that none of the stores bother to mention the size/dimensions of the air filter. The only link I found was on Canada Parts Online, which mentions a specific engine (not cabin) air filter as

> 7 in. L x 6.5 in. W x 1.38 in. HPanel style

It looks similar to mine in proportions.

Are air filters a standard size, within and across companies?

Comment: Apologies if I'm being dense, but your question mentions cabin air filters, but you've linked to normal engine air intake filters.

Comment: @Dan yep, I've barely figured out what the difference is between these two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While some filters may interchange unless it is between different car models of the same brand it is likely coincidence. There will also be interchangability among rebadged or sister brands. As an example some Ford /Mazda or Chrysler/Misubishi may also interchange. Checking Frams cabin filter application guide they list dimensions of the filter. They do not allow for a search by dimensions only.